# How to create in Android a head bubble like in Viber (or something like facebook meesenger has)?

Tags: android, android-service, facebook-messenger, viber

I already created head bubble which works perfectly on older API's until 28.
On latest API 29 I can't open on tap app from background.

Here is head bubble screenshot

[Screenshot of head bubble when an app is in background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlxDN.jpg)

Here is my current code...

```
override fun onCreate() {
      super.onCreate()
      mCallHeadView = 
      LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.call_head, null);
      var params: WindowManager.LayoutParams = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
         WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
         WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
         LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
         PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
      )
      //val params = LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, 
     LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT)
      params.gravity = Gravity.TOP or  Gravity.END
      params.x = 0
      params.y = 270

      mWindowManager = getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE) as? WindowManager;
      if( mWindowManager != null){
         mWindowManager!!.addView(mCallHeadView, params);
      }
      var closeButton = mCallHeadView!!.findViewById<ConstraintLayout> . 
      (R.id.callHead)
      closeButton.setOnClickListener {
         val i = Intent()
         i.setClass(this,MainActivity::class.java)
         i.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
         startActivity(i)
         stopSelf()

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because implementing Bubbles is different in the new versions of Android (28 or higher)
So try to follow [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/bubbles) or any new tutorial like [this](https://blog.mindorks.com/implementing-bubbles-in-android)